# Build failure CLion, CMake, wxWidgets, Mac OS 13.1 Ventura

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, clion, ninja

While trying to learn wxWidgets and CMake, I stumbled across this [link](https://youtu.be/MfuBS9n5_aY) which has the supporting [GitHub](https://github.com/lszl84/wx_cmake_template)

When trying to build this with Clion it fails with the following message:

```
CMake Error at /Users/xyz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8214.51/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/xyz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8214.51/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Users/xyz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8214.51/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:977 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)
```

**The CMakeError.log contains:**

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Some help required resolving this error?  Is it wxWidgets, CLion or CMake?

CMake version is 3.24.2
wxWidgets is 3.2.1

Comment: The error message is about not finding wxWidgets. Have you installed it? How have you installed it?

Comment: Install Xcode and run it at least once to accept a license. When you will accept license CMake will be able to detect compiler. Note: this is also needed after Xcode update!

Comment: I have installed both the command line developer tools and Xcode and also run both via cmd line and desktop to accept the licence.

Comment: within the tutorial, CMake downloads the wxWidgets as part of the build.

Comment: Probably, you follow the tutorial incorrectly: there is no `find_package(wxWidgets)` call at the line 21, as the error message describes. The most suitable call is at the line 15: https://github.com/lszl84/wx_cmake_template/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L15. You need to show your code, otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: I had added some debugging code into the CMakeLists.txt files.  It is all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all that looked at this, the issue is the version of cmake embedded in CLion version 3.24.2.

When I installed cmake with brew and point to that Version 3.25.1, CLion gives a warning showing support for 2.8.11-3.24.x however when compiling it now works.

The tutorials at that link above are excellent.